# SSIS Oracle 32 bit error "Invalid access to memory location."

Tags: sql-server, excel, oracle, ssis, 32bit-64bit

My SSIS extracts data from Oracle DB and loads into the excel file. I am running this package via SQL Job. Now to use Excel providers I have to use 32 bit environment. So I've changed the SQL JOB execution to "Use 32bit runtime".

But now my oracle task is failing with error "Invalid access to memory location."

When I don't use 32bit runtime in job, the **oracle task works** but the excel task fails.

We have both 32bit and 64bit Oracle installed on the server. So not sure why oracle task is failing in 32bit environment.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Detailed error message..

Error code: 0x800703E6.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x800703E6  Description: **"Invalid access to memory location."**.  End Error  Error: 2017-05-09 08:45:31.48     Code: 0xC00291EC  Description: Failed to acquire connection. Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  8:45:30 AM  Finished: 8:45:31 AM  Elapsed:  1.435 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Comment: I am using Oracle Provider for OLEDB to connect to Oracle.. fyi.

Answer (score -1):

I always use TOAD "export to excel" [no coding] option